Saving multiple things using pickle
I am trying to make a password system with Python, and I can't figure out how to save multiple items with pickle. My code works with one item, ie the username, but when I try to add the password, I know it will fail because the password would overwrite the username.
I tried (and this surprisingly worked lol)
import pickle
startup = input('new username or log in? ')
if startup == 'new':
                username = input('username ')
                
 
                class MyClass():
                    def __init__(self, param):
                        self.param = param
 
                def save_object(obj):
                    try:
                        with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
                            pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
                    except Exception as ex:
                        print("Error during pickling object (Possibly unsupported):", ex)
 
                obj = MyClass(username)
                save_object(obj)

                
                password = input('password ')
                
 
                class MyClass():
                    def __init__(self, param):
                        self.param = param
 
                def save_object(obj):
                    try:
                        with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
                            pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
                    except Exception as ex:
                        print("Error during pickling object (Possibly unsupported):", ex)
 
                obj = MyClass(password)
                save_object(obj)

if startup == 'login':
    
 
    class MyClass():
        def __init__(self, param):
            self.param = param
 
    def load_object(filename):
        try:
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                return pickle.load(f)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error during unpickling object (Possibly unsupported):", ex)
 
    obj = load_object("data.pickle")
 
    loginuser = (obj.param)

    attemptuser = input('username: ')

    if attemptuser == loginuser:

        class MyClass():
            def __init__(self, param):
                self.param = param
 
    def load_object(filename):
        try:
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:
                return pickle.load(f)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error during unpickling object (Possibly unsupported):", ex)
 
    obj = load_object("data.pickle")
 
    loginpassword = (obj.param)


    attemptpassword = input('password: ')

    if attemptpassword == loginpassword:
            print('sucesfully logged in')
    
    

My source is https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/save-data-in-python on how to use pickle.

You simply need to pickle a single object that holds both the username and password.  A list containing two strings would do the job - you're not actually benefitting from the use of user-defined classes here.

surprisingly the code worked fine lol

Why is this posted as an answer?  If you want to update the question with more information, then ... update the question.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I mean the code worked first try
